# Python SSL Socket Server with Client Authentication does not accept multiple client certificates

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I would like to create an SSL socket server in which the clients have to authenticate themselves using a certificate. Specifying multiple certificates for handling multiple clients fails.

Via `sslContext.load_verify_locations (cadata = "--------BEGIN ...")` I store the certificates as a concatenated string. However, only the last certificate is then used for the actual authentication. The client that corresponds to the first certificate is not accepted. I use Python 3.9.10 with self-signed certificates. Everything works fine individually.

It seems that the first is overwritten by the last.

Does anyone have experience to that?

Regards, Micha